# Ag grid, prevent table to scale to full width

Tags: html, angular, css, ag-grid

I have a table which scales to all available width even though its content is less .
    Demo: "https://plnkr.co/edit/6L8bTAwkEV6R6Be4M1Qm?p=preview"
Tried to solve it by giving a parent a `width` and ag-grid `max-width` but as you see it has not effect. Has anyone any idea ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not fully got what you wanna to reach? In `plnkr` sample  I see :`style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;"` so with `max-width: 50%` you will get half of page width, but I suppose you are looking something different.

Comment: @un.spike .Thanks I tried your solution BUT infortunately it is still same. I changed data in demo to demonstrate clearly. Please check . https://plnkr.co/edit/dmLF3I4CaAuTNLv5586O?p=preview

Comment: I actually solved this by calling getPreferredWith and assigning this width to grid. But I should call this method each time in sorting, filtering, column toggle  and etc. which can slow performace

Comment: still not clear what result you want to have? 
dynamic grid width according to columns count?

Comment: Spike have you checked the pnkr plnkr.co/edit/dmLF3I4CaAuTNLv5586O?p=preview . As you see it the right column which is sticky is on right edge and there is empty space in the middle which makes table ugly.

Comment: yes, I saw that. but you can change `ag-grid` `width`, that's why I've asked is that require to make it dynamically?

Comment: But in this case ag grid size is dynamic. For example, you have option to hide/show some columns. If I give specific width to table,  the middle space of table will be empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180122/discussion-between-un-spike-and-vugar-abdullayev).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `sizeColumnsToFit()` method.

> **sizeColumnsToFit()**    Gets columns to adjust in size to fit the grid horizontally.

[Official doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#columns)

Code:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    ....
}
```

Modified your [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/en1Ggf4BaAsSfa4mldrS?p=preview)

> Update: explanation of `sizeColumnsToFit`

You need to remember the life cycle of the `ag-grid`.
So in this case, to make `sizeColumnsToFit` works - grid `columns` should be defined and assigned to `gridOptions` property.  If you need to have a dynamic solution, don't forget to inform your grid via `setColumnDefs` first, and then call the `sizeColumnsToFit` method.