# How to have justified columns width that takes all space with AgGrid?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to use AgGrid to display a simple list/grid of text informations.

With the base example :

```
columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
        {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
        {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
    ];

    rowData = [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
    ];

<ag-grid-angular 
    class="ag-theme-balham custom"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and a css style :

```
{
  .custom{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I see that the container of the grid takes all the space, that's cool but in the documentation I don't see a way to make sure the cells are justified and take all the space in width

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ag grid, prevent table to scale to full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344268/ag-grid-prevent-table-to-scale-to-full-width)

Answer (score 2):

You should execute [`sizeColumnsToFit()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#columns) method once [gread is ready](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous):

> **sizeColumnsToFit** : Gets columns to adjust in size to fit the grid horizontally.

as `gridOptions` property

```
gridOptions:{
    onGridReady(params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}
```

or as `html` tag

```
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```